# Why aws UploadFunctionResult not working?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to update a code of **mylamda** from  **dummylamda** but I think there is some problem with methodology of code implementation.

whenever a new **myobject.jar** gets uploaded to **mybucket**, **dummylamda** will be triggered which will deploy **myobject.jar** to **mylambda**.

When I am writing this code I am not able to import the proper package. Below are the specifications:

IDE: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers(Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0))

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#updateFunctionCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.UpdateFunctionCodeRequest-

Java code:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.dummy;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceResult;
import com.amazonaws.ResponseMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaAsyncClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.UpdateFunctionCodeResult;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler  {

     UpdateFunctionCodeResult updateFunctionCode(UpdateFunctionCodeRequest updateFunctionCodeRequest)
       {
           AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().build();
           UpdateFunctionCodeRequest request = new UpdateFunctionCodeRequest().withFunctionName("mylambda-arn")
                    .withS3Bucket("mybucket-name").withS3Key("myobject-key")
                    .withPublish(true);
            UpdateFunctionCodeResult response = client.updateFunctionCode(request);

        return response;

       }   
}
```

POM:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
<artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.475</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.475</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lambda -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.16</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` and work your way back.

Comment: It worked but now I can only invoke updateFunctionConfiguration() and uploadFunction() inside client. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to add **aws-java-sdk-bundle** maveen dependency and need to update the version of other dependencies. So, the updated POM is:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.475</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.475</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lambda -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.475</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.475</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```